# EF Core 3.1 Inconsistent behavior of HasConversion and HasMaxLength mappings in queries

Tags: sql-server, ef-core-3.1

EF Core 3.1 generates low performance query (because of missed index) when filtering per column.

The column that causes the issue is with following mapping:

```
builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                value => value.Value,
                dbValue => new LocationId(dbValue)
            )
            .HasMaxLength(50);
```

LocationId is value object

The query is generated from the following code:

```
_repository.Query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Id == "DD212334234");
```

Where _repository.Query is basically the DbSet of Locations.

Generated query is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [locations] as [l] WHERE CAST([l].[Id] AS nvarchar(max)) = 'DD212334234'
```

Note the CAST to nvarchar(max). The column Id is nvarchar(50) and has index.
The above query against 2.5M records is executed for about 1.2s. 
If I remove the CAST and run the query, it completes for 100ms.

Any help to sorting this out will be much appreciated.

Update: My DbContext is build  with:

```
builder.UseSqlServer(options.ConnectionString, x =>
                    {
                        x.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName);
                        x.MigrationsHistoryTable($"__migrations_{contextName}");
                        x.UseNetTopologySuite();
                    });
```

Another update:

If I comment out the .HasConversion(...), the query is generated without a CAST.
LocationId is like this:

```
public class LocationId : ValueObject
{
    private LocationId(string value)
    {
        Value = value.ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator string(LocationId c) => c.Value;
    public static explicit operator LocationId(string s) => new LocationId(s);

     ...
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (no such CAST in the generated SQL query). EF Core 3.1.3, SqlServer.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks. It's strange, tho. I updated the question with info how the DbContext is built.

Comment: Found the issue - in my test both operators were implicit.

Comment: @IvanStoev you nailed it. Thank you.  I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the operators

```
public static implicit operator string(LocationId c) => c.Value;
public static explicit operator LocationId(string s) => new LocationId(s);
```

hense the expression

```
l => l.Id == "DD212334234"
```

is actually

```
l => (string)l.Id == "DD212334234"
```

which leads to the CAST in the translated SQL.

Initially I wasn't able to reproduce it because in my test both conversions were implicit

```
public static implicit operator string(LocationId c) => c.Value;
public static implicit operator LocationId(string s) => new LocationId(s);
```

so the above expression is actually

```
l => l.Id == (LocationId)"DD212334234"
```

and does not introduce CAST in the generated SQL.

So the solution is to either make the operator `LocationId` implicit, or use explicit cast

```
l => l.Id == (LocationId)"DD212334234"
```

or `LocationId` constructor

```
l => l.Id == new LocationId("DD212334234")
```

or `LocationId` variable.

Or in general, client type comparisons.